# Checking variable correlations

Tags: r, regression, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I am currently doing cox regression models with the `coxph()` function. The formula of my model is:

```
cox.death <- coxph(Surv(diff,event)~Delay+age+female+hba1c+bmi+egfr+sbp+hdl+ldl+
                     smoking+statins+bprx+chf+arrhythmia+valve+pulmcirc+perivasc+htn+htncx+para+neuro+chrnlung+dmcx+hypothy+renlfail+liver+
                     lymph+mets+tumor+rheum+coag+obese+weightloss+lytes+bldloss+anemdef+alcohol+drug+psych+depress,
                   data=cox.model)
```

Then I try to check the proportional hazards assumption with the `cox.zph()` function which is essential for cox models however I get the error:

```
Error in solve.default(imat, u) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.50673e-16
```

As I understand it from looking up this error it means some of my variables are highly correlated? But is there any method of checking which methods are the problematic ones? Because I have a lot of variables in the model it would be better if there is some function I can use to search instead of manually doing it by trial and error. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have general questions about the appropriate use of various statistical methods, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there.

Comment: I've given an answer below but just a comment about coding style, I don't know how high-dimensional your data is but if you're regressing on all variables you can run `coxph(Surv(diff, event) ~ ., data = cox.model)` or if excluding some variables (e.g. "X1" and "X2") `coxph(Surv(diff,event) ~ . - X1 - X2, data = cox.model)`

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of packages for checking multicollinearity. One example:

```
library(usdm)
library(survival)
df = survival::lung 
vif(df[, -c(2, 3)]) # remove outcome columns
```

I believe values greater than 4 are generally considered correlated and above 10 very correlated.